# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "Arman" is not found

Tags: python, discord

I haven't been able to fix this issue even though I've tried everything. There is no error in my code, first it was working, then it stopped working on its own. Also, when the bot starts running, "Bot active!" was writing. Currently, the room does not write, I could not find an error in the codes.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSPOJ.png)

here is my code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: discord runs some function to catch all error - to run bot all time even if there are problems - and this functiond doesn't display these errors. But there should be method to change settings in `logging` to display all errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem when I moved this code to the bottom:
`bot.run("Token")`